# Determining driver by nothing

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, ethernet, lan

I have got this desktop computer with a built-in LAN port. I suspect the OS has been re-installed with a supposedly different OS.

Gigabytes's main support page provides ethernet drivers (Nvidia) only for x32 bit OS, but it is x64 and so these driver downloads are completely pointless.

Now how am I supposed to find the correct driver if it exists at all (it should)?

Comment: Determine the LAN device is,

Comment: like how.. how do I check what it is.

Comment: What is the make and model of your motherboard?

Comment: @Burgi GA-M61SME-S2 (rev. 2.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NIC maybe under **Unknown Devices** or **Other Devices**, but it still has the same information.

In the device manager under the details of the NIC there is a unique hardware identifier.  2 sets of 4 hex digits one for the **ven**dor and one for the **dev**ice id.  You can then google the results.[image: device manager]  [image]

Here is one place to lookup the information. [web site](http://pcidatabase.com/).

[image]

Comment: nice, but.. I don't even have network adapter section. No drivers (more importantly local area connection) is to be found in network adapters.

Comment: @Edenia   The device IS listed under something like **Unknown Devices**  or  **Other devices** Then probably **unknown Ethernet device**.

Comment: I have neither Unknown Devices and Other Devices. In fact, I don't even have a yellow-marked device. Not a single one.

Comment: screen capture it so we can see what you do have in device manager.

Comment: Trust me, I got nothing related to network. Of course, except for the SAMSUNG driver that disappears when I unplug it anyway.

Comment: System Information doesn't recognize ethernet too. Only some irrelevant "miniports" or something.

Comment: Driver update tools doesn't give me anything useful too. I wouldn't post if it was so easy to find it. If it can be found of course.

Comment: Do you have any devices that only show up as **Unknown device**?  It could be named that also.

Comment: No, nothing like that.

Comment: If it doesn't show up, at all, in the device manager it has a hardware issue.  You could,reboot, and mash F2 or F10(your bios could be a totally different key)  and try to get into the BIOS.  See if it is disabled.   If it is not disabled or broken it **will** show up in the device manager somewhere.

Comment: This gets into BIOS with Del. In Integr. Per. there is no onboard NIC or anything.

Comment: I found your motherboard manual and added a picture of the LAN setting in the BIOS.  Make sure the right column is **Auto** and not disabled.

Comment: Okay, I checked for this. It was on Auto already.

Comment: Right click on the computer, scoobypc, in the diagram and **scan for hardware changes**

Comment: I did that several times actually.. And it makes sense that it detected/installed nothing as according to BIOS, everything was just fine. I don't know if it matters though (I wouldn't know, I am using wi-fi on my laptop), but I don't have any cable to put into the lan port. But I am familiar with the fact lights doesn't work when there is one.

Comment: Cable or no cable it should show up in the device manager.  Even disabled devices show up there.  The network card could be dead.

Comment: It isn't much of a card. More like network adapter on board to me.
But you are right. I just told my friend to buy a LAN card. They are cheap as they are nothing special nor complicated.